# DocumentRoot is not changed, Update from Apache2 2.2.22 to 2.4.7

Tags: ubuntu, directory, apache2, virtualhost, document-root

I do have the following problem. I have moved a few websites, with the same hierachy and website structure to a new server with Apache 2.4.7. The old one had 2.2.22.
I've changed the default DocumentRoot to /var/www

For testing I've created a index.html file there with a dot as content. Now I do have a file in /sites-enabled/ with this content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test-w2.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/w2/shop2/website/magento
    ServerName test-w2.de
    ErrorLog /var/www/_logs/w2-error.log

<Directory /var/www/w2/shop2/website/magento>
    php_admin_flag safe_mode Off
    php_admin_value memory_limit 512M
    php_admin_value max_execution_time 600
    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
    php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/w2/shop2/website/magento:/usr/:/tmp
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

That was a working configuration on my old 2.2.22 Apache. Now, when I try to get to the domain, it throws the html file with the dot! If I try test-w2.de/w2/shop2/website/magento it goes to the right directory but obviously that doesn't work pretty well ;)

So its like it ignores the DocumentRoot completly. What is wrong here? The error.log says nothing, access.log obviously says it serves the index.html of /var/www. And there is no configuration error like when I restart the apache.

I also removed the sites-enabled/000-default.conf. The content is moved to the apache2.conf which says:

```
...
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Of course BEFORE the sites-enabled/* stuff is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. There were two things; First was the fact, that the original apache2.conf is searching for *.conf files and my were just named without any extensions. But though, after that mistake, the Virtual Hosts were still ignored. I found out, that the

`Order deny,allow`

and

`Allow from all`

thing has to be replaced with:

`Require all granted`

After that, the config was loaded. There was no error before not even a warning. But that was the problem, that the whole conf File was just ignored.